# Spring Configuration - Inject Mock Beans

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I am using Spring, Junit and Mockito. I need to override beans defined in the main spring configuration using another mockito test configuration (injecting mock beans only as needed). Nested beans have been `@Autowired` in the application.

**Update:**
Based on [alfcope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440100/alfcope)'s answer below, it is important to add the `name` attribute so that spring can allow the primary bean (mock) to override the original one. Otherwise you get this exception:
`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);`

The info message in the spring log shows:
`Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=bar,declaringClass=test.package.MockitoTestConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'bar' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.`

**Example:**
I have a simplified example below that works. Here, Bar is the nested inside Foo, and I need to mock Bar for testing:

```
@Component
public class Foo
{
    @Autowired
    private Bar bar;

    public String getResponseFromBar(String request)
    {
        String response = bar.someMethod(String request);
        //do something else with this reponse
        return response;
    }

} 

@Component
public class Bar {
    public String someMethod(String request) {
        String response = null;
        //do something
        return response;
    }
}
```

Now for testing, let's say I want to inject a mockbar instead of the real bar. How can I achieve this in my test class below?

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class MockitoTestConfiguration {

    //adding the name attribute is important.
    @Bean(name="mockBar")
    @Primary 
    public Bar bar() {
        logger.debug("injecting mock bar");
        return Mockito.mock(Bar.class);
    }
}
```

Actual test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:test-context.xml")

public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    Foo foo;
    @Autowired
    Bar mockBar; //need this to set up the mock response in the test case.

    @Test
    public void testAMethodInFoo_WithBarInjectedByMockito() {

        //set up the mockBar response
        Mockito.when(mockBar.someMethod("1")).thenReturn("1-response");

        String response = foo.getResponseFromBar();
        assertEquals("1-response", response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the `ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader` code I guess you are using xml configuration to define your main bean. If so, just add a name when creating your mockito bean.

```
@Bean(name="mockbar") 
@Primary 
public Bar bar() {
    logger.debug("injecting mock bar");
    return Mockito.mock(Bar.class);
}
```

This way Spring will allow you to have both beans, and as you are using `@Primary` it will be the one used by your tests.

[Spring overriding primary bean with non-primary bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564809/spring-overriding-primary-bean-with-non-primary-bean/42568264#42568264)

[ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#L271)

Comment: I added more detail. Adding a name won't solve what I am trying to achieve. The beans are autowired.

Comment: I can not see any problem with the beans being autowired. That is fine. Do you get the same "error" using a name?

Comment: Sorry I had some other config issues with profile that caused my previous test to not work. I retested with the `name` attribute, and it works just fine. Also, I don't need `@InjectMocks`. I will update for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you use Mockito, you can do this and completely do away with the extra MockitoTestConfiguration class and named primary mock beans in the test profile. Just simply do this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:test-context.xml")

public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    Foo foo;
    @Mock
    Bar mockBar; //need this to set up the mock response in the test case.

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAMethodInFoo_WithBarInjectedByMockito() {

        //set up the mockBar response
        Mockito.when(mockBar.someMethod("1")).thenReturn("1-response");

        String response = foo.getResponseFromBar();
        assertEquals("1-response", response);
    }
}
```